# Will I benefit in terms of memory and speed with JNI?

Tags: java, assembly, java-native-interface, webserver, nasm

I am building a game server in Java. The networking will be handled by JBoss Netty, and I thought I could gain a little extra performance and memory effeciency if I use JNI to call C++ functions which are just wrappers for Assembly code (assembled with NASM) so I/O operations would be done in Assembly, as well as handling large amounts of data. Is there any kind of gain to this approach?

Answer (score 5):

I/O functions are bottleneck'ed by the OS, and assembly will **not** speed up I/O. Neither does switching to C++ or switching to any lower-level language in general.

If you want to improve performance, try **avoiding** I/O.

Comment: Alright, thanks :). But will native code called by the JNI generally be faster?

Comment: Yes, a __very little__ bit. This is not because the I/O is faster, but because the general resolving of variables, and stuff like that doesn't go through a virtual machine but straight in machine code. The difference is minimal though.

Comment: If at all. Don't optimize too early and don't underestimate the possibilities of a JIT compiler. There are possibilites of optimization a JIT compiler uses which a C++ compiler is not able to use. Therefore it is not clear whether you will really benefit from calling native code. Especially if you have to cross the boundary between Java code and native code very often.

Comment: So the overall opinion is that this is a "no-go"?

Comment: @Benjamin: I'd say more or less yes. There might be some corner cases where it makes sense. But that would appear only after you have shown that is not possible to achieve the desired performance with the Java plattform.

Comment: The main good reason to use JNI is when you have a dedicated C/C++ library you need to use, or for very specific uses (like heavy computation involving 3D matrix). Here you will lose simplicity for very hypothetical performance increase. Also remind that Java->native methods calls have a slight overhead with respect to a Java->Java call.

Answer (score 2):

This is case to case basis.  If in between I/O it involves huge amount of computations / processes / memory access that Java has less efficient implementation than C++ then YES you will definitely have performance gains.  In many cases, this is true.

But think carefully if performance gain outweighs your ability to debug that certain process.  It will be very hard to pinpoint where the problem is if it occurs inside your JNI call.

Usually with servers it is more important to be able to tell what's the problem and fix it rather than go to the extremes in pushing the performance, since server performance can also be gained easily by additional hardware (faster components, clustering, etc) unlike client-side programs where you are often stuck with a default hardware.